# Neo4j Constraining Values, Labels or Properties

Tags: database-design, neo4j, constraints, data-modeling

I'm coming from a RDBMS background and trying to wrap my head around property graphs (neo4j in particular). The biggest thing that irks me is there doesn't seem to be a way I can constrain things like

- Node Labels

  - Nothing to stop `:person`, `:Pperson`, or `:PURSONNN`
- Relationships

  - Nothing to make sure you you're not adding edges applications don't know how to make use of. For instance, maybe there's a "CanViewAccount" relationship, but someone else comes along and naively constructs a edge "CanView"
- Nothing to constrain properties of nodes or edges.

  - I might want to have a "UserType' a `:Person` can be, which should be only one of a handful of pre-defined options.

This is RDBMS 101 stuff (a la referential integrity constraints), but I'm not sure if and how I might do something similar in Neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that Neo4j is schema less, that's why you can do all the stuff you have listed.

On the other side, Neo4j has some constraints like :

- a uniqueness constrainst on a property for a label. Example, the property `email` should be unique on nodes `:Person`
- a require constraint on a property for a label. Example, the property `email` must exists on nodes `:Person`
- a require constraint on a property for a relationship type. Example, the property `since` must exists on relationship `:KNOWS`

And in the EE version, you can create a primary key (called `node key`) on one or many field

Comment: Thanks for the info. The whole "no schema" thing seems to be touted as a good thing by most NoSQL DBs I've come across, but a total absence of such support is a bit of a shame. Feels like my options are either to hope for the best, or patch a second system (be it a simple KVM database, a relational database, or whatever else) to constrain it from just being an unmanagable web of different terms and elements.

Comment: There are also a lot of advantages to be schema less, but it's not the question here. In most use cases, write queries always come from the same pipe, so it's easy to handle/constraint the schema, but it will be in the application layer